# Angular 2 modal with materialize wont open

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get a modal to open when the component loads but nothing is appearing and i cant see why. Any help would be great.

component.html:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" materialize="modal" [materializeActions]="actions">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuizService } from '../services/quiz.service';
import { Answer, Question, Quiz } from '../models/index';
import {MaterializeAction, MaterializeDirective, MaterializeModule} from "angular2-materialize";
import "materialize-css";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz',
  templateUrl: './quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.sass'],
  providers: [QuizService]
})
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  actions = new EventEmitter<string|MaterializeAction>();
  quiz: Quiz = new Quiz(null);
  pager = {
    index: 0,
    size: 1,
    count: 1
  };
  selections: [string]

  constructor(private quizService: QuizService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openModal()
  }

  openModal() {
    this.actions.emit({action:"modal",params:['open']});
  }
}
```

I have tried googling all over and figure out what im missing. Any help would be great

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasnt working for me was because i was presenting it as a modal but it was linked as a new page with a new path. So once i removed this link the modal worked.